# Handling NULL Values in DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sql query which works in SQL server.

```
DATEADD(hour,-QT.[SpecPeriod],AG.[START TIME]) ahStart
```

In places where Specperiod is null then the calculated ahStart field is populated with null, otherwise, ahStart field is populated with AG.[START TIME] minus whatever the value is in SpecPeriod

I have to execute the above query in different tool where is creates an issue. When it finds an empty value in  Specperiod, it throws exception when doing the DATEADD calculation.
So I modified the query as below but the 'NULL' after the ELSE statement isn't working and throwing exception. Can you please advice the best approach to handle the empty values in SpecPeriod while doing DATEADD calculation?

```
CASE WHEN QT."SpecPeriod" IS NOT NULL then DATEADD('hour',-QT."SpecPeriod",AG."START TIME") ELSE 'NULL' END ahStart
```

Comment: remove the single and double quotes

Comment: What is the data type of `SpecPeriod`?  It should be a number.

Comment: Datatype of specperiod is tinyint

Comment: The double quotes are OK (although I believe not needed for "SpecPeriod"), but you shouldn't have the single quotes around 'hour' and the last 'NULL'.  i.e. try `CASE WHEN QT."SpecPeriod" IS NOT NULL then DATEADD(hour,-QT."SpecPeriod",AG."START TIME") ELSE NULL END ahStart`

Comment: This worked in my tool (Tibco data virtualization)CASE WHEN QT."SpecPeriod" IS NOT NULL then DATEADD('hour',-QT."SpecPeriod",AG."START TIME") ELSE NULL END ahStart

Comment: The sql version is : CASE WHEN QT.SpecPeriod IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(hour, - (QT.SpecPeriod), AG.START TIME) ELSE NULL END. Thanks everyone for your comments.